# jQuery parseHTML result not as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML in a string from a remote file. Now I want to read some elements with jQuery.
The external HTML is here in the string

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                var htmlString = '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
                        '<html>' +
                        '<head>' +
                        '<meta name="firstName" content="false">' +
                        '</head>' +
                        '<body>' +
                        '<div id="test1" class="test1" name="test1">test2</div>' +
                        '<div id="test2" class="test2" name="test2">test2</span>' +
                        '</body>' +
                        '</html>';

                var $ = jQuery;
                var html = $.parseHTML(htmlString);
                //var html = htmlString;

                var test1 = $("#test1", $(html)).attr("name");
                var test2 = $(html).find("div[class='test2']").attr("name");
                var test3 = $(html).attr("name");

                console.log(html);
                console.log('1: ' + test1); //undefined
                console.log('2: ' + test2); //undefined
                console.log('3: ' + test3); //firstName

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

can someone explain to me why I can not select an item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.parseHTML` parses out the `head` and `body` tags as they are generally not wanted when you insert something into a DOM that already has a `head` and `body` tag, so you end up with an array looking like

```
[meta, div#test1.test1, div#test2.test2]
```

containing the meta tag and the two div's.

As the div's are now root elements, they are not children of anything, so using jQuery's `find()` won't work, as it only finds descendant elements.

Using `filter()` however will work

```
$(html).filter('.test2').attr("name");
```

or if you're unsure of wether the elements are root elements or children of some element,  you can append the array of elements to a wrapper element, and then use `find()`

```
$('<div />', {html : html}).find('.test2').attr('name');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/uv5kbr9o/)